# Get DISTINCT column based on another DISTINCT column in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 columns in a table name products

```
id|p_name| p_img       |
1 | Xs   | xsmax.png   | 
2 | Xs   | xr.png      | 
3 | XR   | xs.png      |
```

I want to get DISTINCT value of p_name and echo its p_img. So I used the code below.

But, it displays the all the p_image because there are no duplicates. I want to display based on the p_name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_name, product_img FROM products
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

}

expected output
p_name| p_img       |
Xs    | xsmax.png   |  
XR    | xs.png      |
```

Comment: Please also add your expected output.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: And what is the logic behind why `xsmax.png` is shown for `Xs` rather than `xr.png`?

Comment: How do you decide which p_img to display when there are multiple entries with the same p_name?

Comment: The names are all of simplicity, the images are different because each product has multiple colors. For example, XS has 4 entries with same names but the image are different because has multiple colors. I want to show what product we have in the index page so I want to show only one with the first image that is in the entry and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need an aggregation in the subquery use :

```
SELECT product_name, product_img 
  FROM products
 WHERE (id, product_name) in
       ( SELECT MAX(id), product_name
           FROM products
          GROUP BY product_name   
       )
```

depending on *"so I want to show only one with the first image that is in the entry and ignore the rest."*

Comment: Thank you, it works after I remove the q. May I know what is the 'q' for?

Comment: yes you need to remove @Tinagaran , I added because  *every derived table must have its own alias* but this is not the case. So, I edited.